# Postgres auto-reconnect

Tags: go

I'm wondering if it makes sense or is possible to achieve Postgres auto-reconnections. The idea is to listen in and ping the server to determine if the heart beat is active, if not it should attempt a reconnection. The goal is to constantly ensure that the db is live and operable.

So far I've managed to implement `database/sql` and my ORM (sqlboiler) with an interval that pings however the ping for some reason doesn't detect a drop when I disable the db server. But when I reboot the Go app it knows that the connection isn't available! Weird.

Comment: Why don't you just implement a connection pool? When one connection dies, you just create a new one in the pool.

Comment: Perhaps check for a successful response in the ping function?

Comment: I do have a connection pool @Games but the goal is to detect and stop my service rather than just attempt reconnecting.